# how do I check the version of weka.jar and weka source code

Tags: java, version, weka

I guess it is possible to check the version of a weka.jar, but how can I do that?
Also, I think it is also possible to check the version of weka source code, where can I find it?
The information on JAVA doc are mainly about the revision or version of this specific class (I guess). Is there a overall version for the whole source code?

I need this information to compare the source code I am working on and the jar my professor gives me. They are not compatible.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many libraries have such information in MANIFEST.MF file in META-INF directory:

```
Specification-Title: Apache POI
Specification-Version: 3.8-beta5
Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: Apache POI
Implementation-Version: 3.8-beta5
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to look at the directory where the code is from. However, what if I only have the .jar file.

Comment: This is part of jar. Just open it and you will see. Jar is ZIP file.

Answer (score 4):

```
java -cp /path/to/weka.jar weka.core.Version
```